# Sorting on two datetime columns, results in duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I log vehicle entry/exits to a building. I am using the below procedure to sort on the existind dates for entry/exit when I display the data, but it results in duplicate rows? Anyone know how I can remove the duplicates?

```
select id, plate,log_entry,log_exit,logged_by,driver_name,remarks,carimage,flagged
from ((select *, log_entry as filterdate
       from vehicle_log
      ) union all
      (select *, log_exit as filterdate
       from vehicle_log
      )
     ) thelog
where
((log_entry >= _startDate and log_entry <= _endDate) or (log_exit >= _startDate and log_exit <= _endDate))
and plate like concat('%', _plateNumber, '%')
and driver_name like concat('%', _driverName, '%')
order by filterdate desc;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `UNION` on your subselect because you are using the same table and obviously will have duplicate rows.

Comment: Sure, could you provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explain what you're trying to achieve. You're using the `UNION` to sort on the `log_entry` and `log_exit` like one field. Fair enough, by I really don't see how that gives anything different from simply sorting on `log_entry` and `log_exit` as two separate fields. So unless you have a good explanation for that, I'd say the best answer is this:

```
SELECT id, plate, log_entry, log_exit, logged_by, driver_name, remarks, carimage, flagged
FROM vehicle_log
WHERE ((log_entry >= _startDate AND log_entry <= _endDate)
    OR (log_exit >= _startDate AND log_exit <= _endDate))
AND plate LIKE CONCAT('%', _plateNumber, '%')
AND driver_name LIKE CONCAT('%', _driverName, '%')
ORDER BY log_entry DESC, log_exit DESC;
```

**EDIT** for your last comments: To merge the `log_entry` and `log_exit` columns into one for the purpose of filtering, and assuming that they cannot be both `NULL`, try this:

```
SELECT id, plate, log_entry, log_exit
FROM #vehicle_log
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN log_entry IS NULL THEN log_exit ELSE log_entry END) DESC;
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/385895/495843/).

If you want the combined field in your `SELECT`, try this:

```
SELECT id, plate, log_entry, log_exit
     , (CASE WHEN log_entry IS NULL THEN log_exit ELSE log_entry END) AS filterdate
FROM #vehicle_log
ORDER BY filterdate DESC;
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/385896/495844/).

Comment: Hi Racil, I want to get a result as if there was only one datetime column, if that makes any sense?

entry
exit
entry
entry
exit

and so on

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. But merging them in one column will not give you any different results that `order by log_entry desc, log_exit desc;`. And in both ways you will not get entry exit entry entry exit unless each entry has its exit before the next entry. You need to give us some sample data to work with. Mainly we need to know if you have the entry and exit in the same row or if different rows, and if in different rows, then are you using `NULL` for the unused column?

Comment: Racil, thanks for your effort in this matter. Ill provide some sample data after a meeting im currently about to have. Will be back in about two hours. Again, thanks alot!

Comment: Hello Racil (and everyone else), I have now made a fiddle for testing purposes. I simplified the query above to just the important parts:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19ec2/1/0

The results Im looking for is (full rows, but Im just writing the plate numbers here):

BBB222
AAA111
CCC333
DDD444

... and again, should be the full rows with id, plate, log_entry, log_exit and so on. Hope this helps?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the data there, not in a fiddle. Anyway, the data you've provided is not useful. You have 4 different cars (i.e. different plates) two entered and two exited. That's not real, so the cars which entered never exited, and the other two exited without entering. You need to post more realistic data. Plus I think each car will have more that one entry & exit. For now, I've just changed your data to be for 2 cars instead of 4. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Racil, just because a car enters on a specific date, does not mean it leaves on that specific date as well so the data is correct.

Comment: Also, your list would be correct if the last entry was the first. Im looking for a way to treat the two date time columns as if it was a single date time column and then sorted desc. The plate has nothing to do with the sorting.

Comment: I made a new dataset as per the one you used. I think the plate and other info it throwing us off track a bit: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/385884

Just imagine that I want the result here ordered from Dec 4 down to Dec 1. It that a better explanation?

Comment: OK, check my edit. I don't really understand the logic, but I think my edit gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Racil, works just as I wanted it! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this query was designed to give two rows, one for the entry time, another for the exit time - outputting both to a column called filterdate.

This query could be vastly simplified by removing the union, and sorting on exit time - which is wat I assume your after

```
select id, plate,log_entry,log_exit,logged_by,driver_name,remarks,carimage,flagged
from vehicle_log
where ((log_entry >= _startDate and log_entry <= _endDate) 
        or (log_exit >= _startDate and log_exit <= _endDate))
      and plate like concat('%', _plateNumber, '%')
      and driver_name like concat('%', _driverName, '%')
order by log_exit desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use [distinct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) ? select distinct id ...

Comment: As Davide said. This does not provide the correct results as per the dates